# Is it possible to count two columns in the same query

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table structure:

```
t1
-------------
id // row id
userID_follower // this user is a follows another member
userID_following  // other member that this user
```

Is it possible to run a single query to combine both of the following:

1. how many users this person is following

   > select COUNT(id) from t1 WHERE userID_follower = ".$myID." 
   >   ."
2. how many users follow this person

   > select COUNT(id) from t1 WHERE userID_following = ".$myID."

Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In MySql, You can use the `SUM()` function over a condition, since a false condition will equal to `0`, and a true one will equal to `1`:

```
SELECT SUM(userID_follower = $myID) AS followerCount,
   SUM(userID_following = $myID) AS followingCount
FROM t1
WHERE userID_follower = $myID
   OR userID_following = $myID
```

Comment: Oh my god. This gives so much adventage over counting subsets without filtering the whole select over the `where`-clause. Thanks very much!

Comment: why do you need the where clause ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed The columns should be indexed. there is no need to do a full table scan.

Comment: @TheScrumMeister, could not understand what you said. What is the problem if the where clause is omitted ?

Answer (score 11):

The more Hoyle(ISO) solution would be using a Case expression:

```
Select Sum( Case When userID_follower = $myID Then 1 Else 0 End ) As followerCount
    , Sum( Case When userID_following = $myID Then 1 Else 0 End ) As followingCount
From t1
Where userID_follower = $myID
    Or userID_following = $myID
```

Comment: Didn't event need the CASE because my column was an int. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend returning two rows with one count on each row, instead of two columns:

```
SELECT 'follower', COUNT(*) AS count FROM t1 WHERE userID_follower = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'following', COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE userID_following = ?
```

This may seem like a degenerate solution, but the reason is that if userID_follower and userID_following are indexed, this can utilize the indexes.  If you try to get the results in two columns as shown in the other answers, the can't use the indexes and has to do a table-scan.

Other tips that are tangential to the question:

- There's no advantage to using COUNT(id) in this case.
- You should use SQL query parameters instead of interpolating $myID into your query.

Comment: `the can't use the indexes and has to do a table-scan`, That is incorrect. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: @Scrum: Aha, you're right, if I test with a few thousand rows with more random data, MySQL does decide to use indexes and perform a union merge.  I had tested with too few rows, or not enough random distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
select ownerID, count( distinct userID_follow), count(distinct userID_following) from t1 group by ownerID
```

Comment: Oh, you're right, but how do I get the count value? shall I as AS cont1 and AS cnt2?