# Get all ages count on a table

Tags: mysql, count, timestamp

My goal is to get how many users I got on my database per year.
I save the birthday in a timestamp.
After reading this solution 
[How to count 2 different data in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525407/how-to-count-2-different-data-in-one-query)

makes me wonder, if the oldest member I have is 120 old, will I have to write 120 cases each will count "between" the two timstamps that defines a year?

That sounds a bit odd, there's no other way to get the job done?

Desired result :

age 1 - 0 people

age 2 - 1 people

.

.

.

age 20 - 314 people

age 21 - 30 people

.

.

.

age 25 - 47 people

.

.

age 120 - 1 people

Comment: Why not just use `group by`?

Comment: How exactly? I will still need to group by 120 times, each time for the timestamps between each age? or am I missing something?

Comment: your missing doing a group by on a computed field ( being age )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want one query for each age.  Assuming you have a query that can calculate age to the nearest year, then you can get a count with

```
SELECT (..expression..) AS "age", count(*) FROM USERS GROUP BY "age"
```

If you're looking for the the `(..expression..)` to compute the ages, you probably want something close to

```
EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - EXTRACT(year FROM birthdate)
- IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),"%c%d") < DATE_FORMAT(birthdate,"%c%d"),1,0)
```

but there are other (probably more efficient) versions you might prefer.