# PHP MySQL Group By question

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a column inside my table: `tbl_customers` that distinguishes a customer record as either a LEAD or a CUS.

The column is simply:  `recordtype`, with is a char(1).  I populate it with either C, or L.
Obviously C = customer, while L = lead.

I want to run a query that groups by the day the record was created, so I have a column called: `datecreated`.

Here's where I get confused with the grouping.

I want to display a result (in one query) the COUNT of customers and the COUNT of leads for a particular day, or date range.  I'm successful with only pulling the number for either `recordtype`:C or `recordtype`:L , but that takes 2 queries.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  SELECT COUNT(customerid) AS `count`, datecreated 
    FROM `tbl_customers` 
   WHERE `datecreated` BETWEEN '$startdate."' AND '".$enddate."' 
     AND `recordtype` = 'C' 
GROUP BY `datecreated` ASC
```

As expected, this displays 2 columns (the count of customer records and the `datecreated`).

Is there a way to display both in one query, while still grouping by the `datecreated` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(customerid) AS `count`,
    datecreated,
    SUM(`recordtype` = 'C') AS CountOfC,
    SUM(`recordtype` = 'L') AS CountOfL
FROM `tbl_customers` 
WHERE `datecreated` BETWEEN '$startdate."' AND '".$enddate."' 
GROUP BY `datecreated` ASC
```

See [Is it possible to count two columns in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133388/is-it-possible-to-count-two-columns-in-the-same-query/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a group by with over multiple columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(customerid) AS `count`, datecreated, `recordtype`
FROM `tbl_customers` 
WHERE `datecreated` BETWEEN '$startdate."' AND '".$enddate."' 
GROUP BY `datecreated` ASC, `recordtype`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, depending on whether you want the two counts in separate rows or in separate columns.

In separate rows:

```
SELECT datecreated, recordtype, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_customers
WHERE datecreated BETWEEN '...' AND '...'
GROUP BY datecreated, recordtype
```

In separate colums (this is called *pivoting* the table)

```
SELECT datecreated,
       SUM(recordtype = 'C') AS count_customers,
       SUM(recordtype = 'L') AS count_leads
FROM tbl_customers
WHERE datecreated BETWEEN '...' AND '...'
GROUP BY datecreated
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(c.customerid) AS count,
                         c.datecreated,
                         SUM(CASE WHEN c.recordtype = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfC,
                         SUM(CASE WHEN c.recordtype = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfL
                    FROM tbl_customers c 
                   WHERE c.datecreated BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('%s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') 
                                           AND STR_TO_DATE('%s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
                GROUP BY c.datecreated",
                  $startdate, $enddate);
```

You need to fill out the date format - see [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for details.