# Select two counts in one query

Tags: sql, count

I have users(user,pass,email) table and I want to get the count of user where user='someuser'
and the count of email where email='someemail' in one query and I came up with that:

```
SELECT (

SELECT COUNT( user )
FROM users
WHERE user = 'someuser'
), (

SELECT COUNT( email )
FROM users
WHERE email = 'someemail'
)
FROM users
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think that having two aggregate columns on two different tables work without this subquery approach, so I think your solution is ok.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5177386/944634)

Comment: @ParagBafna: that's a fine approach, and I note that it requires MySQL's "promotion" of booleans to integral types.  (We don't know that lam3r4370's RDBMS does this.)

Comment: @Parag Bafina and which approach is better? I mean mine or this in the link?

Comment: @lam3r4370 That solution is better than nested query( but i am not 100% sure). you can execute and check the performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that is the correct way to do it in your case. Your counts will probably always be 0 or 1 and be satisfied from an NC index.

In case you want to scan more data, it can be more efficient to do it like this:

```
select sum(case when user = 'x' then 1 end) UserCount, sum(case when email = 'x' then 1 end) EmailCount
from users
```

This will always scan the table. It depends on the data which version is faster. In your case, yours is faster.

Comment: Your solution is worse than the solution proposed in the original post. Because your query makes a complete table scan once it don't have a where clause.

Comment: @arpf you're right in that a table scan always occurs (that's dangerous so I call it out in the answer). My version is better, though, if a table scan was always required. Also, note the first sentence - I mention that tradeoff.