# join two table and count

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this kind of structure

kode data

```
+------------+-----------+
| code | ket             |
+------------+-----------+
|20401 | code one        |
|21401 | code two        |
|22401 | code three      |
|etc   | etc             |
+------------------------+
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
| id  | code1           | code2     |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+
|1    | 20401           | 21402     |
|2    | 21401           | 22401     |
|3    | 22401           | 20401     |
|4    | 20401           | 21401     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

how tow count and sum to achieve output like below

`+-----------+-------------+-------------+
 |code       | count code1 | count code2 |
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+
 |code one   |      2      |     1       |
 |code two   |      1      |     1       |
 |code three |      3      |     1       |
 |etc        |     etc     |    etc      |
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+`

basicly what i want is select table **ket** and count in **code1** and **code2** that hace the code with one query.

Comment: Asked multiple times before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133388/is-it-possible-to-count-two-columns-in-the-same-query

Comment: Also when asking questions such as these please illustrate what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform two joins:

```
SELECT    ket AS code, 
          cnt1 AS "count code1"
          cnt2 AS "count code2"
FROM      kode
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   code1, COUNT(*) AS cnt1
           FROM     data
           GROUP BY code1) c1 ON kode.code = c1.code1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   code2, COUNT(*) AS cnt2
           FROM     data
           GROUP BY code2) c2 ON kode.code = c2.code2
```

Comment: work like charm, and i dont know that we can join like that, before i create multi query select code loop with php and select count(*) where code=code code1 and select count(*) count2 where code=code in the loop. thanks