# Simple and Efficient Code to Count Data in PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I think there's will be a simple and efficient code to count data with PHP and get the data output from different MySQL tables. This implementation is used to display how much data in my dashboard page.

But I prefer to use PHP procedural style because I'm still learning.

So here is my dirty code:

```
$count_admin = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_admin FROM employee WHERE level_id = 1");
$count_officer = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_officer FROM employee WHERE level_id = 2");
$count_goods = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_goods FROM goods");
$count_customer = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_customer FROM customer");

$row_admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_admin);
$row_officer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_officer);
$row_goods = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_goods);
$row_customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_customer);

echo $row_admin['count_admin'];
echo $row_officer['count_officer'];
echo $row_goods['count_goods'];
echo $row_customer['count_customer'];
```

Comment: $count_admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_admin FROM employee WHERE level_id = 1"));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5177386/18078362 try this method if you have same table

Comment: @pk_ thank you. This solution helps me when I try to fetch 2 condition on the same table.